# Why does my code return the receiver?

Tags: ruby

I am implementing the `each` method on my own. I am supposed to explicitly return `self` before closing the method. This is my code:

```
module Enumerable 
  def my_each
    for i in self
      yield i
    end
    #self
  end
end

[1,2,3,4].my_each {|x| x + 1} # => [1,2,3,4]
```

Why does the code still return the receiver even though I did not explicitly return `self` on the last line?

Comment: Because `for i in self` returns `self`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> why does the code still return self even though I did not explicitly return self on the last line?

If you don't specify a return value explicitly, a method will return the last expression evaluated. The last expression in your method is the `for` loop.

From its [documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/doc/syntax/control_expressions_rdoc.html#label-for+Loop):

> The result value of a `for` loop is the value iterated over unless `break` is used.

Examples:

```
for i in 1..10
end
#=> 1..10

for i in [1, 2, 3]
end
#=> [1, 2, 3]

for i in [1, 2, 3]
  break :foo
end
#=> :foo
```

Comment: Thanks (answered) :)